# Had Z3 used the user provided patterns for the smtComp results in the "AUFLIA-p" section?

Tags: z3, smt

I am testing the generality of some simplifications (mainly: a directed partial quantifier instantiation). Therefore I ran a collection of the benchmarks in the "AUFLIA-p" section of the smtComp with and without simplification. In order to have as less as possible side effects, I am interested in running Z3 without (user provided) patterns.

I examined some benchmarks in the "AUFLIA-p" section, and I am wondering why the benchmarks of this section contain patterns. Maybe you have run Z3 for this section with an option for disabling patterns. Recently, I just dropped the patterns form some benchmarks an observe the dramatic performance decrease.

Questions:
Is there any difference between the "AUFLIA-p" and "AUFLIA+p" sections?
How can I tell Z3 to ignore the (user provided) patterns?

Regards,
Aboubakr Achraf El Ghazi

Answer (score 2):

The difference between AUFLIA-p and AUFLIA+p is that the first contains no patterns, but the latter does. There is however only one category of benchmarks in SMTLIB, called AUFLIA. (Some of) These benchmarks contain patterns which during SMTCOMP are removed before running the tools. For example, compare [unscrambled benchmark](http://www.smtexec.org/exec/benchmarkDetail.php?benchmark=2297999) and the [scrambled benchmark](http://www.smtexec.org/exec/benchmarkDetail.php?benchmark=2297999&scrambled), where the first does contain patterns, but the latter does not.

I believe the removal of patterns is done through the [benchmark scrambler](http://smtcomp.sourceforge.net/2012/tools.shtml).